# How to ssh into docker-machine VirtualBox instance?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

docker-machine version 0.2.0
docker version 1.6.2

I'm using [docker-machine to create a machine using VirtualBox](https://docs.docker.com/machine/#getting-started-with-docker-machine-using-a-local-vm).  Everything works fine but I'd like to ssh into the machine itself and I find no instructions on how to do this.  I can connect to the ssh port:

```
ssh $(docker-machine ip dev)
```

But I've no idea what username / password / identity file to use.

Comment: If you -1 put a comment and explain what is wrong with this question and allow the asker to amend.

Comment: the recommanded docker way to connect inside a container is `docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec

Comment: @user2915097 The question was to ssh into the machine itself not a docker container

Comment: A lot of Docker questions get downvoted if they have no programming content. Arguably, this question should be on SF, but it's a judgement call really.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can log into docker-machine hosts by just running

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

(Using the "default" host here)

The identity files should be stored under `~/.docker/machine/machines`. If you want to log into a container (as opposed to the host), use `docker exec` as suggested by user2915097.

Comment: So i have another PC (different from the one used to setup the remote host) and i want to be able to access it via docker-machine on this PC (just like i am doing from the one used to provision). How do i go about that?

Answer (score 73):

if you really need to do it via `ssh`, this is working with docker 1.8.2

init docker:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

get the IP from your default docker machine:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

this prints something like this out: `192.168.99.100`

```
ssh docker@192.168.99.100
```

password is `tcuser` but you can also use the identity file, see other answer

Comment: I am very curious about how you got to know that the password is ```tcuser```. Would you reveal your secret, please? :-)

Comment: found somewhere else, but you can see it also here: https://github.com/docker/machine/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tcuser

Answer (score 25):

Finally, I found an answer :

I'm on Windows with Docker Toolbox (Docker Machine).

If I `docker-machine -D ssh default`, I find that the SSH parameters should be :

Host : localhost
Port : 51701
User : docker
Key : .docker\machine\machines\default\id_rsa

When I change my Putty/MobaXterm settings to match, voila, I can SSH into the container.

Comment: Hey, thank you. Found your answer on top of results. Saved me from hours of frustration. +1

Comment: To add, in my case SSH port was 58361. All the required details are printed when using -D flag.                                                                               `Using SSH client type: external
{[-o BatchMode=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Users\<user>\.docker\machine\machines\default\id_rsa -p 58361] C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe}`

Comment: Where I can get it from `docker-machine inspect`? It printed non local address in `Driver->IPAddress` variable

Answer (score 12):

For the hackers out there, here is a script that will ssh into the 'active' docker-machine. This also gives you the values for the ssh_key, ssh_port, and the ssh_user, making it possible to do things like `rsync` between the localhost and the VM.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker_machine_name=$(docker-machine active)
docker_ssh_user=$(docker-machine inspect $docker_machine_name --format={{.Driver.SSHUser}})
docker_ssh_key=$(docker-machine inspect $docker_machine_name --format={{.Driver.SSHKeyPath}})
docker_ssh_port=$(docker-machine inspect $docker_machine_name --format={{.Driver.SSHPort}})

ssh -i $docker_ssh_key -p $docker_ssh_port $docker_ssh_user@localhost
```

You can copy and paste that into your terminal, line for line, and it will work. Or, make the script into a function, and feed it the name as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you'd rather use the `ssh` command rather than `docker-machine ssh`, you can do

```
ssh `docker-machine ip machine_name` -ldocker -i ~/.docker/machine/machines/machine_name/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

For mac OX,the machine and its keys are located here (make sure you have the keys in there, something like the below:

```
~/project/dev/docker_notes za$ ls /Users/za/.docker/machine/machines/default/
.DS_Store        ca.pem           config.json      disk.vmdk        id_rsa.pub       server-key.pem
boot2docker.iso  cert.pem         default/         id_rsa           key.pem          server.pem
```

1) list available vms.

```
> ~/project/dev/docker_notes za$ docker-machine ls
>     NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
>     default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.11.0
```

In my case, the name of the machine is default. So, just

```
~/project/dev/docker_notes za$ docker-machine ssh default


                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.11.0, build HEAD : 32ee7e9 - Wed Apr 13 20:06:49 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990
docker@default:~$ vi 
.ash_history  .ashrc        .docker/      .local/       .profile      .ssh/         log.log
docker@default:~$ ls
log.log
```

As you can see, I am able to ssh into docker-machine/instance.

```
docker@default:~$ uname -a
Linux default 4.1.19-boot2docker #1 SMP Thu Apr 7 02:41:05 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

You can also follow this > [howto - docker](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use use the ordinary synatx used on your terminal
login :docker && pasword:tcuser

exemple : ssh docker@192.168.99.X
pw:tcuser

Answer (score -1):

We can also ssh into the docker via following command -

docker exec -it  /bin/sh