# Docker container IP address

Tags: docker

I use Docker on Mac OSX.

After running a container, I check IP address.

```
docker inspect container-name | grep IP
"LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
```

Now when I go to 172.17.0.5, there is no response.

Then check IP address in another way.

```
docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.102
```

192.168.99.102 works.

Now my question is why it outputs different IP address and the first one doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a Docker container's IP address from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host)

Answer (score 5):

the Docker daemon is linux-specific software, therefore to run on OS X, it must run inside a linux virtual machine. Using docker machine takes care of this for you. The IP address `172.17.0.5` is the address of that container on the docker bridge inside the linux virtual machine, and therefore it is not reachable from the OS X host machine.

The command `docker-machine ip default` returns the IP address of the virtual machine itself, which is reachable from the OS X Host machine.

If you SSH into the docker-machine virtual machine, then you would be able to reach `172.17.0.5` from within that SSH connection. For how to do this, see this answer: [How to ssh into docker-machine VirtualBox instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330442/how-to-ssh-into-docker-machine-virualbox-instance)

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can "expose" ports too. This means that if you would like to access port `80` from a device which is not the VM (in this case) you can do something like `-p 8080:80` (where `80` is the port within the container, and port `8080` is the port on the host). `192.168.99.102:8080` would then be accessible and route to `80` within the container.