# How to ssh docker machine by xshell

Tags: docker

I know I can type docker-engine ssh default on xshell, but the content will be wired, and if I press ctrl + c which is very often to break command on  Linux, it will leave the docker machine, if I use command ssh 192.168.88.100 it asked username and password, what are the username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I use command ssh 192.168.88.100 it asked username and password, what are the username and password

It should *not* ask you for a username/password if ssh does find the proper public/private key in the `$HOME/.ssh` folder of the account doing the ssh command.
Check [XShell](http://www.xshellcn.com) ssh config (such [as those shown here](http://www.xshellcn.com/xmg_column/xbn-dl.html)) to see if you can specify your public/private key used for connecting to the docker-machine ([they are here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817273/6309)).

Comment: I found the username and password, it's docker and tcuser

Comment: OK, but still: if your public/private keys were correctly configured, you would not need to use username/password.